# Relation between linear transformation and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this problem but do not know how to approach it. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ be a linear transformation. Then which of the following is *true*?

(A) $T$ must have some real eigenvalues which may be less than 4 in number.

(B) $T$ may not have any real eigenvalues at all.

(C) $T$ must have infinitely many real eigenvalues.

(D) $T$ must have exactly 4 real eigenvalues.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/eigen3/eigen3.html) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Complex_eigenvalues) out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Consider the transformation $T(x)=Ax, \ x \in \mathbb R^4$ where 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: thanks for the example.I have checked the matrix A and have seen that all eigenvalues are imaginary.So T may not have any real eigenvalue at all.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Make your life easy and assume $T$ to be diagonal...